# Visual Studio 2017 + Nuget + dotnet new

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

Is it possible to package with nuget a number of projects as templates all in one package? (to be used with dotnet new). I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Do you mean pack a number of projects in one package, then add the package in the templates? If yes, You have to define your own nuspec manifest and list containing assemblies in files section:
<file src="A\bin\Release\A.dll" target="lib\net40" />. If  I understand this question incorrectly, could you please describe your question more detail?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Just create a NuGet package with multiple templates.